# Excel: create multiple rows based on "amount" column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a dataset in Excel that looks like this:

| Customer | Amount | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 4 | City B |
| Patrick | 3 | City A |

And a bunch of other columns.

I am looking for a way to get to this:

| Customer | Amount | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 4 | City B |
| John | 4 | City B |
| John | 4 | City B |
| John | 4 | City B |
| Patrick | 3 | City A |
| Patrick | 3 | City A |
| Patrick | 3 | City A |

So in essence, get a record for every Amount value.
It's for a one time import operation so it doesn't have to be dynamic or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next lines to reflect actual data source and columns
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer", type text}, 
        {"Amount", Int64.Type}, {"City", type text}}),

    #"Repeat Rows" = 
        Table.FromRecords(
            List.Combine(
                List.Accumulate(
                    {0..Table.RowCount(#"Changed Type")-1},
                    {}, 
                    (state, current)=> 
                        state & 
                            {List.Repeat(
                                {#"Changed Type"{current}}, 
                                Record.Field(#"Changed Type"{current},"Amount"))
                            })
                    ))
in
    #"Repeat Rows"
```

[image]